# Codility: CountDistinctSlices. What am I missing?

Tags: ruby, algorithm

The Codility Question Is Here: https://codility.com/programmers/lessons/15-caterpillar_method/count_distinct_slices/

Now, my solution is below:

```
def solution(m, a)

  end_idx = 0
  hash_of_elements = {}
  last_idx = a.size - 1
  slice_right_now = []

  slice_counter = 0

  while last_idx >= end_idx

    el_to_add = a[end_idx]

    while !hash_of_elements[el_to_add].nil?
      element_to_remove = slice_right_now.shift
      hash_of_elements.delete element_to_remove
      #puts "removing #{element_to_remove} from the slice. the new slice is #{slice_right_now}. Hash is #{hash_of_elements.inspect}"
      puts "#{slice_right_now.inspect}" if slice_right_now.size > 1
      if slice_right_now.size > 1
        slice_counter += 1 
        return 1000000000 if slice_counter > 1000000000
      end
    end

    #puts "Adding #{el_to_add} to the list!"
    hash_of_elements[el_to_add] = true
    slice_right_now << el_to_add
    puts "#{slice_right_now.inspect}" if slice_right_now.size > 1
    if slice_right_now.size > 1
      slice_counter += 1 
      return 1000000000 if slice_counter > 1000000000
    end
    end_idx += 1

  end

  puts "Number of slices other than indivisual elments are #{slice_counter}"

  slice_counter += a.size

end
```

It is a Ruby Solution. For the input: 6, [1, 3, 4, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1]

It gets the following slices:

```
[1, 3]
[1, 3, 4]
[3, 4]
[3, 4, 1]
[3, 4, 1, 2]
[4, 1, 2]
[1, 2]
[2, 1]
[2, 1, 3]
[1, 3]
[1, 3, 2]
[3, 2]
[3, 2, 1]
```

In addition to this, each element of the array is a slice also.

The answer is wrong however apparently.

The answer to that input is supposed to be 24. Mine is 22. I don't understand what I am missing.

Comment: For anybody who may come across this at a later date: The key observation to make is that if an array has: size of 1, it will have 1 slice. If size of 2 then 2 + 1 slices possible. If 3 then 3 + 2 + 1. And so on. So, you do not have to enumerate the slices, just count them as the array length changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

24 is correct, as you can easily check with brute force solutions that go over *all* slices and count the distinct ones:

```
(1..a.size).sum { |k| a.each_cons(k).count { |s| !s.uniq! } }
=> 24

(1..a.size).sum { |k| a.each_cons(k).reject(&:uniq!).count }
=> 24

(0...a.size).sum { |i| (i...a.size).count { |j| !a[i..j].uniq! } }
=> 24

(0...a.size).to_a.repeated_combination(2).count { |i, j| !a[i..j].uniq! }
=> 24

(0..a.size).to_a.combination(2).count { |i, j| !a[i...j].uniq! }
=> 24
```

If you don't just `count` but *print* them, you'll see that you're missing the slice consisting of `[4, 1]` and the slice consisting of `[2, 1]` at the end.

The fishing lesson is: If the problematic case is small enough that you can solve it with trivial brute force, do do that and compare its findings with your more clever attempt's findings.

Comment: Thank you! That makes a lot of sense.